# Override Spring's EntityManager (intercepting repositories' methods to alter it's query)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, aop, entitymanager

The goal is, adding filtering capabilities to JPARepository exactly the same way as Pagination and sorting capabilities exists! It's completely separated from the business query (either by providing @Query or use the method name convention)

So what I suspect is that EntityManager's createQuery methods is responsible for translating method name into Query using CriteriaQuery or whatever is passed to, or the @Query sql string! so is that true?

If yes, then how can I override it to inject my filters in query?

If no, then how/where can I do so?
Do I need to override some sort of Spring Data Aspect which intercept the calls itself and return the right query!!

Comment: Spring does not have an `EntityManager`, a JPA provider does.

Comment: As far as my understanding, JPA is a specification, Hibernate is one of the implementations. Spring data is a layer in between! is that correct?

Comment: a layer ON TOP. You don't use the JPA API when using "Spring Data JPA", you use the Spring Data JPA API. Would have thought their docs would mention that

Comment: Exactly, so there is an EntityManager somewhere! Can it be overridden?

Comment: Spring Data JPA will simply call the JPA Providers query method (and nobody said there isn't an `EntityManager` ... I said THE JPA PROVIDER does). And no you can't "override" what an EntityManager does unless you hack into the code of your JPA provider (or your JPA provider allows some extension to do that). Anything in `@Query` will be processed by Spring Data JPA, not the JPA provider, and fed into the JPA provider.